# Append second datatable to existing datatable

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

What I am trying to do is modify this code so I can fetch a second datatable to append, how do I append results of a second datatable?

```
        Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
        Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("connectionstring")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        Dim Family_id = lbFamilies.SelectedItem.Value
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Family_id=@Family_id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family_id", Family_id)

        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

        sqlConnection1.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        myDataTable.Load(reader)
        sqlConnection1.Close()
        lbProduct.DataSource = myDataTable
        lbProduct.DataTextField = "product_name"
        lbProduct.DataValueField = "product_id"
        lbProduct.DataBind()
```

Comment: So, you want to add the results in myDataTable to the existing rows in lbProduct.DataSource instead of replacing lbProduct.DataSource with myDataTable?  Is that right?

Comment: @squillman yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two have the same schema, try this.

Replace:

```
lbProduct.DataSource = myDataTable
lbProduct.DataTextField = "product_name"
lbProduct.DataValueField = "product_id"
lbProduct.DataBind()
```

With this:

```
CType(lbProduct.DataSource,DataTable).Merge(myDataTable);
lbProduct.DataBind();
```